# Python filter(predicate, current, threshold)

Tags: python, lambda, filter, predicate, threshold

I'm working on a school exercise about lambdas where you have to fill in code to get the program working. I can see what the result has to be but I just cant get my ideas converted in code. Could you help?

This is the exercise:
*FILTER takes as input a function (predicate) and two numbers (current and threshold). It creates recursively a string where the numbers (from current to threshold) are kept only if the result of applying the predicate to such numbers is true.

predicate1 checks if the input is divisible by 2

predicate2 checks if the input is divisible by 3

Test1: uses predicate1

Test2: uses predicate2*

This is the code: the underlines is where I can put code:

```
def filter(predicate, current, threshold):
  if ________ > _________
    return ''
  else:
    _______________________
    _______________________

threshold = 20
predicate1 = lambda x: x % 2 == 0
predicate2 = lambda x: x % 3 == 0
res = filter(predicate1, 1, threshold)
print()
```

I came up with this below but it isn't working:

```
def filter(predicate, current, threshold):
  if current > threshold:
    return ''
  else:
    new_result = filter(predicate, predicate(current), threshold)
    result =  str(predicate(current)) + ' ' + new_result
    return result

threshold = 20
predicate1 = lambda x: x % 2 == 0
predicate2 = lambda x: x % 3 == 0
res = filter(predicate1, 1, threshold)
print()
```

any tips?

Comment: You should try to understand what kind of value `predicate` returns, and what kind of value `current` should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter(predicate, current, threshold):
    if current > threshold:
        return ''
    else:
        return (str(current) + " " if predicate(current) else '') + filter(predicate, current + 1, threshold)

threshold = 20
predicate1 = lambda x: x % 2 == 0
predicate2 = lambda x: x % 3 == 0
res = filter(predicate1, 1, threshold)
print(res)
```

When you have lambda or a function that returns "x == y" or any other operator it - will return a boolean.

Also each time you calling the function you have to add 1 to your current variable, otherwise you will get infinite loop function.